# Do I need to be at the Eurostar terminal 90 minutes to 2 hours before my train leaves?

Tags: uk, public-transport, eurostar

I will be travelling to Brussels tomorrow from St Pancras on the Eurostar. On the Eurostar website, it indicates that you must be at the station at least 90 minutes before hand if you are travelling on a Standard ticket:
[image: St Pancras check in times]
The above screenshot are the times for St Pancras International, which gives the median time for how long you need to get to the station, check in, and get on board the train. At the other ends of the time (Paris and Brussels) the time listed to get seated is between an hour to 2 hours, depending on the station.

For those that have frequently travelled this route, is it really necessary to leave 90 minutes (or longer) in order to get on board the Eurostar?

Comment: Having traveled from London to Amsterdam several times recently I can assure you that the 30 minutes on the tickets are the real last entry, unless staff at the entrance allow you to enter later.

Comment: It's always possible there are unusual delays (e.g. due to industrial action, illness, fire evacuation, etc), but if you turn up before the minimum time stated, you have more recourse than if you arrived 31 minutes before departure and found a massive queue.

Comment: At St Pancras currently (early 2023) there is a shortage of border officials needed to stamp the passports of departing UK passengers (blame Brexit). This is driving an almost 30% increase in the time it takes to process passengers departing from London compared with before Brexit and the pandemic. Eurostar is capping the proportion of seats sold on many services to prevent unmanageable queues and delays. Some trains – which have a capacity for 900 passengers – are running with 350 seats unsold.